# MUI alert component conflicts in css

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI 5.10.11 and the MuiAlert component sometimes goes wrong.
This is what it should looks like when severity='error'
[image]

However in some pages, it looks like this
[image]

Below are my codes. Can anyone have a look at it and try to figure out what's wrong with my work?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Snackbar } from '@mui/material';
import MuiAlert from '@mui/material/Alert';

const Alert = React.forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={24} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});

export default function MessageDialog(props) {
  const defaultPosition = {
    vertical: 'top',
    horizontal: 'center'
  };

  const autoHideDuration = 5000;

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeoutId;

    if (props.open) {
      setOpen(true);
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        setOpen(false);
      }, autoHideDuration);
    }

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  }, [props.open]);

  return (
    <>
      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: defaultPosition.vertical,
          horizontal: defaultPosition.horizontal
        }}
        open={open}
      >
        <Alert severity={props.type} sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
          {props.children}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </>
  );
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

The fault is due to the css that I spotted out in the screenshots.

Comment: Does it happen even after clearing cache and refreshing the page? Or only during development with hot replacement?

Comment: I run the app on localhost with the command "next dev" (Without the quotes)

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: I've found out the problem to my project. Although I'm using MUI v5, some packages like material-ui-icons are out-dated. Updating all those libraries solved my problem quite well. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like problem comes from `Mui` component class name which is `MuiPaper-root`. In page with white `background` it overrites because probably some other `Mui` components have same class name and you are using white background with this component or you have a css file with white `background` assigned to `MuiPaper-root` class in that page

Comment: Those classes are automatically added by MUI, I haven't add any class to the components yet.

Comment: I know they are MUI class names that’s why I’m saying you should check other components which includes same class names in that page @namln-hust

Comment: You seem to have a point here. Anw, I've found out the problem to my project. Although I'm using MUI v5, some packages like material-ui-icons are out-dated. Updating all those libraries solved my problem quite well. Thanks for your time!